# loop through excel sheets to delete specific sheets and rename others

Tags: c#

I want to iterate through all sheets on an excel file to delete a specific sheet and rename another. My script renames the sheet that I want to delete and ignores the one I want to rename and I don't know how to fix it.

I've tried using a counter to move from workbook.Worksheets.Item[1] (the sheet I want to delete) and workbook.Worksheets.Item[2] (the sheet I want to rename to master).

```
                    try
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show(Path.GetFullPath(fileDirectory_Source + cleanFileName).ToString() + "\r\n");
                        var sheetNumber = 1;
                        ///Standardize Excel Sheet Names
                        var excelFile = Path.GetFullPath(fileDirectory_Source + cleanFileName);
                        var excel = new Excel.Application();
                        var workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(excelFile);
                        var sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.Item[sheetNumber];
                        MessageBox.Show(sheet.Name);
                        foreach (Excel.Worksheet s in workbook.Worksheets)
                            if (s.Name.Equals("Customer Details"))
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show(sheet.Name);
                                    sheet.Delete();
                                    sheetNumber++;
                                    //sheet = sheet.Next();
                                }
                        MessageBox.Show(workbook.Worksheets.ToString());

                        sheet.Name = "master";
                        new Excel.Application().DisplayAlerts = false;
                        workbook.CheckCompatibility = false;
                        workbook.DoNotPromptForConvert = true;
                        workbook.Save();
                        excel.Application.Workbooks.Close();
                        GC.Collect();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                        errorText = errorText + "Error at Excel File Manipulation Step: " + ex.Message.ToString() + "\r\n";
                    }
```

Comment: You're changing the "Sheets" collection when you delete the "Customer Details" sheet, which can cause things to get out of sync.  Instead of deleting the sheet, just assign the sheet to a variable and if the variable isn't null, delete the sheet.  If you were deleting multiple sheets, you would add them to a collection and then use it to delete the sheets.

Comment: I wish the sheet was being deleted, but it isn't. It seems that the collection is in tact, except that the script renames the Customer Details sheet (which is incorrect).

Comment: If your first sheet is "Customer Details", your code will rename it. You start with "sheetNumber" = 1 (Excel is "1 Based"), so "sheet" is the first sheet in the workbook.  If you're expecting the "sheet" to be the second WorkSheet (as it would be if it was "1 Based"), then you're going to get the results you're seeing.  If you're expecting "Customer Details" to be the 2nd sheet, then change "sheetNumber" to "2".